# Cannot map on element from axios response react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to map on an array, but this is not work,
You can found code here : https://codepen.io/ilaan16/pen/eYRKgOm

```
    setUtils(result.data);
    if (!utils) {
      console.log("ERROR_UTILS", result);
    } else if (utils) {
      console.log("UTILS_OK", result);
    }
```

My console display me always (except the first time, before refresh) this :
[image: image1]

You can see "success: true" and in data I have what I want make in utils (by setUtils)
But is not working correctly...
Thanks you for your helping ! If you have any question please tell me.

PS : I'm using react typescript with React F.C

Comment: Please share more code: the fetching of data, the structure of response, the hook you're using..

Comment: setUtils will only set the value to util on its next render, it will not instantly set the value. you can check the update in next render, in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ProfileComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [utils, setUtils] = useState<MyUtils>();

  useEffect(() => {
    get_utils();
  }, []);

  const get_utils = () => {
    fetch(
      "https://localhost:30001/v2/utils/language"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        const tempUtils = result;
        if (!tempUtils ) {
          console.log("ERROR_UTILS", result);
        } else if (tempUtils ) {
          console.log("UTILS_OK", result);
          setUtils(result.data);
        }
      });
  };
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

setUtils will only set the value to util on its next render